# Ação botão Bluetooth em BroadcastReceive (Android studio) **Java**

Tags: android-studio

Estou criando um App em android studio**(Java)** e Preciso parear um botão via bluetooth exemplo: botão de pau de selfie que quando acionado ele abra uma activity mesmo o aplicativo estando minimizado se possivel fechado imaginei em  BroadcastReceiver mas não encontrei nada relacionado. desde já agradeço.

Mainactivit ->

```
AudioManager mAudioManager;
ComponentName mReceiverComponent;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        MediaButtonIntentReceiver r = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();
        filter.setPriority(1000); //this line sets receiver priority
        registerReceiver(r, filter);
        mAudioManager =  (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mReceiverComponent = new ComponentName(this,MainActivity.class);
        mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mReceiverComponent);

    }
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        mAudioManager.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(mReceiverComponent);

    }
```

---

MediaButtonIntentReceiver -> BroadcastReceiver

```
public class MediaButtonIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public MediaButtonIntentReceiver() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String intentAction = intent.getAction();
    if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
        return;
    }
    KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (event == null) {
        return;
    }
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // do something
        Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    abortBroadcast();
}
    }
```

---

meu manifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sysystem.vaipf">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".MediaButtonIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

esse é o exemplo que usei por ultimo porem sem sucesso.

Oque eu preciso é quando apertar o botão do controle bluetooth ele abrir a mensagem `Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` do BroadcastReceiver porem ao apertar o botão não acontece nada!!!
Lembrando que o botão a que me refiro é aquele controle de pau de selfie!

Comment: @Maniero O desenvolvimento do aplicativo é em java(android studio) o botão que preciso capiturar a ação é de pau de selfie por exemplo mas não sei se consegui me expressar bem, e realmente estou precisando dessa força...

Comment: Importante você [edit] seu post e explicar detalhadamente o problema, descrevendo o que tentou e onde está a dificuldade atual (deixando só as tags realmente relevantes para o problema em si). Tutoriais e dúvidas amplas não se encaixam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic), é importante fazer cada pergunta sobre um problema bem específico (até porque, depois de resolver uma dúvida pode abrir outra pergunta). Aqui tem umas dicas para melhor aproveitamento do site: [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help].

Comment: se puder verificar agora eu agradeço muito e me desculpe, como disse sou novo aqui e não peguei o jeito ainda mas eu chego lá.

Comment: Ainda falta uma descrição do que aconteceu de errado (o que esperava que acontecesse, e o que aconteceu em vez disso, em especial se ocorreram mensagens de erro, e em que linha). Um [MCVE] pode ajudar bastante.

Comment: Acho que me expressei melhor agora muito obrigado pela ajuda e se estiver faltando mais alguma informação colocarei com prazer!

Comment: Boa noite!!! Como não obtive exito em usar o botão do pau de selfie migrei para o botão do fone de ouvido. Não ficou como esperado mas está funcionando. caso alguma boa alma tenha a solução ficarei grato mas enquanto não ficara dessa forma mesmo, mesmo assim muito grato pela ajuda dos moderadores em tentar me ajudar a redigir a pergunta...

Comment: procure sempre detalhar bem nas próximas e dê uma lidinha nos links recomendados acima quando tiver um tempinho, ai aumenta a chance de sucesso.